# accessing array from application delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

i have declared 1 array in application delegate

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *books;
```

i have added objects to this array in XMLParser.m

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])
        return;
    NSLog(@"i m in didEndElement");

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {
        [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook]; //here i have added objects to array

        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;

        NSLog(@"books=%@",appDelegate.books);
    }
    else 
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

i have declared this array in XMLParser.h like this

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject {
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    Book *aBook; 
}
```

now i have to access this array in BooksDetailViewController.m , how do i access this array.
in short  how i can access array from application delegate into BooksDetailViewController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should have to `alloc` and `init` your array, then You can add objects in it.

You should have to create AppDelegate instance in your `BooksDetailViewController` like this,

in .h file

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

and in .m file

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Now you can access your array like this,

```
appDelegate.books
```